# NULL property type acquiring more Size: Google App Engine Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

In my application, various db Kind are defined with numbers of kind's properties(some are indexed and some aren't indexed)

But am surprised, after seeing, **Null** size spacing around 950 MB in 20 GB,

[image]

Is there any way to optimise this?

**Note**: at few properties of kinds doesn't have default values, Do i need to define default values?

Ex.

```
class terminals(db.Model):
   location_code = db.StringProperty()
   terminal_code = db.StringProperty(default='')
   pass_code = db.StringProperty(indexed=False)
   print_format = db.StringProperty(indexed=False)
   start_invoice_no = db.IntegerProperty(indexed=False, default=1)
   next_invoice_no = db.IntegerProperty(indexed=False)
   use_jzebra = db.BooleanProperty(default=False, indexed=False)
   last_doc_details = db.TextProperty(default='{}')
   last_modified_on = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
```

And also, some of the properties are rarely used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can shorten the names for the datastore properties themselves when you construct them as I believe they also count towards the total storage limits.

```
username = ndb.StringProperty(name='un')
username = db.StringProperty(name='un')
```

and you can refer to `.username` but it'll be stored as `'un'` in the datastore, saving precious bytes.

So perhaps your null fields have 'long' names and there are many instances of them.

Link for db: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/propertyclass

```
name
```

> The storage name for the property, used in queries. This defaults to the attribute name used for the property. Because model classes have attributes other than properties (which cannot be used for properties), a property can use name to use a reserved attribute name as the property name in the datastore, and use a different name for the property attribute. See Disallowed Property Names for more information.

Comment: is the same method applicable for db.model also??

Comment: Could you help me over here? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870637/gae-db-model-property-using-name-param

Comment: I had a look at that but I don't know I'm afraid.