# GAE: db Model property using 'name' param

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-models, google-cloud-datastore

Trying to optimise db model class property name by using `name` in the property.

Ex.

```
class terminals(db.Model):
   location_code = db.StringProperty()
   terminal_code = db.StringProperty(default='')
   start_invoice_no = db.IntegerProperty(indexed=False, default=1, name='sin')
   next_invoice_no = db.IntegerProperty(indexed=False)
   last_doc_details = db.TextProperty(default='{}')
```

Query on terminals:

```
terminal_qry = db.Model(terminals).all()
```

putting happening fine into db. but while i try serialize this query object.

```
serializers.serialize('json', [terminal_qry])
```

its raising the error as,

```
AttributeError: 'terminals' object has no attribute 'sin'
```

Could any one tell this, where went wrong here?

Regards.

Comment: It might be a bug in the serializers library you are using.

Comment: I don't think so, because even if i try to open the admin of django,
it showing same error. AttributeError: 'terminals' object has no attribute 'sin'

Comment: What is `serializers.serialize`? You're going to need to be specific about what libraries you use if you want any useful responses.